# Firestore Security Rules and Next.js restricting access (RBAC)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-security

I am currently working on an app where I need to restrict access for reading, writing (etc..) a document in a collection. However, I am still able to fetch the data.

**Brief explanation of the structure and code:**

*(I have simplified the code and images for ease of understanding)*

This is a representation of the current **Firestore** structure:
[image: Image of the structure of a group]

I have a collection of "groups", whereas each group will have members and owners. Every user is defined in the collection of "users" and is assigned a user-ID (the user-IDs are used for assigning users to a group).

**Firstly**, Let's say you want to fetch all groups (`GET /api/groups`), all groups given from the API should be all the groups you are a part of. If you are not a part of the group, it should not be returned.

If I'm part of a group I would expect to GET a list of groups;
e.g.

```
[
 {groupName: 1, members: ["..."], owners: ["myId"]},
 {groupName: 2, members: ["myID"], owners: ["..."]}
]
```

If I'm not a part of any groups, I would expect an empty list `[]` or some error..

**Next.Js:**

In the file `pages/api/groups/index.tsx` I have created an API handler that fetches all the available groups in the collection "groups":

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import db from 'config/db';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const groupsRef = await db.collection('groups');

    if (req.method === 'GET') {
      const groups = await groupsRef.get();
      const groupsData = groups.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      res.status(200).json(groupsData);
    }

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
       ...
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).end();
  }
}
```

**Firestore Rules**

For ease of testing I have created a simple rule that should restrict any READING or writing from the collection "groups":

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /groups/{id} {
     allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

**After Publishing, I expected** an error or empty list. I however still got the data from groups when fetching the data in e. g. `pages/index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetcher = (url: string) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);

export default function index() {
   const { data, error } useSWR('/api/groups', fetcher);

   console.log(data);
   console.log(error); 

   if (!data) { ... }
   if (error) { ... }

  return (<div> ... </div>)

}
```

**Have I misunderstood the purpose of Firestore Rules? Or is there something wrong with the security rules? Why do I still get the data?**

*[EDIT] (answering Dharmaraj's question):*

> Can you share import db from 'config/db'; file? Are you using the Admin SDK (that bypasses all the security rules)?

inside `/config/db/index.js`

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from './serviceAccountKey.json';

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  try {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Firebase admin initialization error', error.stack);
  }
}
export default admin.firestore();
```

Comment: Can you share `import db from 'config/db';` file? Are you using the Admin SDK (that bypasses all the security rules)? Also ` db.collection('groups').get()` will fetch all documents from the collection. And **Security rules are not filters**. You need to specify that in your query e.g. if you are fetching your groups then use `.where("members", "array-contains", "USER_ID")`

Comment: Thanks for answering! I added the config/db to the main question, below `[EDIT]`. I am using the "firebase-admin" package, so I guess I'm using the Admin SDK(?).. If so, that explains why I'm struggling, thanks for clarifying! Ok, I'll keep in mind that security rules are not filters. Thanks! @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) that has privileged access to your Firebase services and bypasses any security rules. Also, [*Security rules are not filters*](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003). You need to specify that in your.

If you are fetching your groups then use `.where("members", "array-contains", "USER_ID")`. Otherwise you are fetching the whole collection.